# Android Service: wait for response from Broadcast receiver within a Timer task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Ok, due to my lack of experience with Android, I may have got this slightly wrong, however it all works.  Sometimes I get an unexpected result. Here is severely abridged code using Timer:

```
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        initializeTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 10000);
    }

public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
        runSendJob(jsonData, SentReceiver);

        // wait up to 10 seconds for response from broadcast receiver
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(bResult.equals(false) && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<10000){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (bResult.equals(true)){
            UpdateLog();
            }
         }
    };
}
}
```

initializeTimerTask() runs fine every 10s when "idling" with nothing to do, but if runSendJob does some work it takes maybe 10-20 seconds to complete while waiting for the BroadcastReceiver to respond, set the return flag and continue on, then the Timer immediately runs again.

I want it to wait 10 seconds, so I've revised as follows. It seems to work nicely now, waiting 10s before cycling around again (thanks for the tip @notTdar);

```
public class MyService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver SentReceiver;
public Boolean bResult;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler();
    commandStart()
}

private void commandStart() {
        if (mExecutor == null) {
            mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            Runnable runnable =
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startMyTask();
                        }
                    };
            mExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, DELAY_0, DELAY_10, DELAY_SECONDS);
        d(TAG, "commandStart: starting executor");
    } else {
        d(TAG, "commandStart: do nothing");
    }

DeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch(getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            bResult = true;
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            bResult = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}; 

    registerReceiver(SentReceiver, new IntentFilter("MSG_SENT"));
}

public void startMyTask() {

    runSendJob(jsonData, SentReceiver);

    // wait up to 10 seconds for response from broadcast receiver
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(bResult.equals(false) && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<10000){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (bResult.equals(true)){
        UpdateLog();
        }

    // spin off other jobs here if I want to...
    mHandler.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateSomethingElse();
                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: improvement, remove timertask use handler (recommended) for the recurring task.

Comment: Good idea @notTdar I'll look into that

Comment: issues like when unexpected occurs, it quits w/o throwing an exception and onResume(), serivce does not have that.

Comment: Thanks @notTdar Correct, Service doesn't support onResume(), was copied from MainActivity just to show Broadcast was Ok (full code too big for here). Working on implementing ScheduledExecutorService instead of Timer at the moment... so far, so good :o)